# Управление пользователями Tomcat с помощью Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

В tomcat-users.xml задаются пользователи с определенными правами. Возможно ли, чтобы эти пользователи задавались из Spring Security некоторого приложения?

Comment: Главный вопрос: зачем?

Comment: @Maksim   Дело вот в чем. Мне нужно стримить аудио файлы, на страничке приложения есть <audio>. В tomcat звуковой файл задан как ресурс с определенным url. Так вот мне надо, чтобы доступ к нему был у ограниченного набора пользователей, зарегистрированных в spring-security. Я как-то задавался здесь вопросом, как стримить звук средствами Java, но ничего не нашел. Поэтому выбрал такой вариант, сейчас это работает, но без ограничений по правам

Answer (score 1):

Управление пользователями через сервер приложений (при том, что Tomcat - это контейнер сервлетов) - путь Java EE. Spring - самодостаточная технология, которая не требует серьезной серверной обвязки. Предлагаю посмотреть в сторону интеграции вашей системы с сервисом управления доступом. Например, OpenLDAP + midPoint. С первым вы всегда можете работать через LDAP коннектор в Spring Security ([документация](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-authentication)). А midPoint может быть использован в качестве единого сервиса управления пользователями и контроля доступа ([документация](https://wiki.evolveum.com/display/midPoint/OpenLDAP)).

---

**Update**

Относительно вашей ситуации с audio: наличие данного тега на странице должно регулироваться настройками доступа в приложении, а не из Tomcat. И почему у вас ресурсы стримятся через Tomcat? Доставку также можно организовать через приложение.

Comment: Тег я могу и не показывать, но фактически доступ к аудио по урл все равно остается. Возможно, подскажете, как это из приложения реализовать? Обычная байтовая запись в OutputStream не подходит

Comment: Почему не подходит?

Comment: Причин несколько. Во-первых, <audio> сначала должен получить мета-информацию о звуке (длительность, автор, название), во-вторых если мне нужно проигрывать не с начала, с другого места, я перемещаю туда ползунок, и подгрузка идет с этого места. Tomcat такой стриминг умеет

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://gist.github.com/davinkevin/b97e39d7ce89198774b4

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @carapuz если ответ и комментарий были полезны, то прошу оценить